Disable the sorting of one column from react material ui - table sorting
I am using this version of the materail ui - sortable table.

I want to create an avatar col that doesnt get a sorting arrow
          {
            id: 'id',
            numeric: true,
            disablePadding: true,
            label: 'Id',
          },
          {
            id: 'avatar',
            numeric: true,
            disablePadding: true,
            label: '',
          },
          {
            id: 'name',
            numeric: false,
            disablePadding: true,
            label: 'Name',
          }

I am using the same code from the sandbox here
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#sorting-amp-selecting
https://codesandbox.io/embed/xdn3tn?module=/src/Demo.tsx

What would you do -- if you didn't want to sort by calories for example -- or/and you had a  nested row with a picture, name - markup inside it - could you get the table to sort via a data-attribute?
I can't find any documentation that would resolve what should be a minor thing.
<TableSortLabel
  active={orderBy === headCell.id}
  direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
  onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
>

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-sort-label/
do I modify it like this?
<TableSortLabel
  active={isActive? orderBy === headCell.id: false}
  direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
  onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
  hideSortIcon={isActive? false:true}
>


Why call <TableSortLabel/> for columns which do not have sorting?

I was going directly off the demo example when I made this as a component -- but I'd rather push props to disable it -- then call a different component with the same props

The child component of <TableSortLabel> can be directly rendered. I mean like this isActive ? <TableSortLabel><ChildComponent/><TableSortLabel/> : <ChildComponent/>

I got it working by adding an isActive property --- but the only problem is I have to add the property to true for everything rather than just add it and make it false for what I dont want sortable
    <TableSortLabel
      active={headCell.isActive? orderBy === headCell.id: false}
      hideSortIcon={headCell.isActive? false:true}
      direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
      onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
    >

